# FileNotFoundException found on Soffid Syncserver after reconfiguration

Tags: identity

I've just reconfigured Soffid sync server, and now I can see this error messag in the log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/opt/soffid/iam-sync/conf/keystore.jks (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Please at least share your configuration so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the ownership of the directory iam-sync. You can use the chown command (Linux command):

```
sudo chown -R soffid /opt/soffid/iam-sync
```